# Cannot Show Values From Google Sheet To Google Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am following a video regarding how to show values from Google Sheets to my Google Web App. I could gather the values in server-side (checked it from the log) with this code:

```
function getTableData(){
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MvKhVObm34dijEDMW7zNQ1bDciwjvM5zDqtSGy3TGjw/edit#gid=0";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("IPP Gol I-III");
var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues();
return data;
}
```

But I cannot show the values to my web app. Here's my code to show the values:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData(); 
});

function generateTable(dataArray){
  var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

dataArray.forEach(function(r){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textcontent = r[0];
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textcontent = r[1];
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textcontent = r[2];
  var col4 = document.createElement("td");
  col4.textcontent = r[3];

  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  row.appendChild(col4);
  tbody.appendChild(row);

});
}
```

If you need to see my entire code, here is the sample of my Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MvKhVObm34dijEDMW7zNQ1bDciwjvM5zDqtSGy3TGjw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You forgot the dot before `getTableData`. And since you do not listen for exceptions, it gets swallowed

Comment: Oh gosh yeah I forgot the dot. But it still doesn't show the values tho

Comment: Good :) Then, the usual questionnaire: 1. Are you accessing the `/dev` endpoint? 2. If you access `/exec`, did you redeploy after the change? 3. What does console say? 4. Add a `withFailureHandler` and pass a logging function to it, run, repeat 1 - 3. 5. If added, add a `try...catch` for the server-side code and log the error, repeat 1 - 3.

Comment: I was thinking about why the tbody variable is not detected on the appendChild

Comment: I do it in /exec and I already redeploy the project, the console also does not say anything error

Comment: Ok, then: 6. Did you redeploy with version incremented? 7. If you log something before `google.script.run`, but inside the handler - is it logged? 8. If you log `dataArray` before starting to create anything - is it logged?

Comment: Oh I managed to fix it now. I moved the tbody inside the forEach. Thank you @OlegValter!

Comment: huh, and it worked? That's unexpected... Did you change something alongside the move?